# Refining a C# lambda query to access second related field in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

OK...making good progress on this, but needing to go a bit further than currently.

I have two related tables, `billing_transactions` and `billing_transaction_accessorial_charge`. The second is the many to the first one.

The second table has a type and a charge, I need to know in my query if it has none, one or both of them as well as what the charge amount is.

The types for `service_code_id`

```
1 (meaning this delivery is a residential delivery) 

2 (meaning it has a dish machine)
```

A delivery can have both. The charge for that is stored in a field called charge.

I currently have this:

```
var gridData = (from d in db.billing_transactions
                where (d.Id > 954 && d.Id < 958)
                select new
                            {
                                d.base_amount,
                                d.Id,
                                dishmachine = d.billing_transaction_accessorial_charge.Where
                                    (p => p.service_code_id == 2),
                                residential = d.billing_transaction_accessorial_charge.Where
                                    (p => p.service_code_id == 1),
                            }
                ).ToArray();
```

This returns a count of how many dishmachine or residiental charges there are, but I have not been able to figure out how to get the second field in it.

The database structure for the child table is:

```
id 
service_code_id 
billing_transaction_id
amount
```

anybody have any ideas?

Joe

EDIT: Here is the final code block:

```
 var gridData = (from d in db.billing_transactions
                        where (d.Id > 954 && d.Id < 958)
                        select new
                        {
                            d.base_amount,
                            d.Id,
                            dish_charge = d.billing_transaction_accessorial_charge.Where 
                            (p =>   p.service_code_id == 2)
                            .Sum(l => l.amount),
                            dish_count = d.billing_transaction_accessorial_charge.Where
                            (p => p.service_code_id == 2),
                            res_count = d.billing_transaction_accessorial_charge.Where
                            (p => p.service_code_id == 1),
                            res_charge = d.billing_transaction_accessorial_charge.Where
                            (p => p.service_code_id == 1)
                            .Sum(l => l.amount),
                        }
                      ).ToArray();
```

Comment: The Second field as in amount?

Comment: yes....and thank you for the formatting help.  I am going to research how to better format on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will `Sum` the `amount`, if that is what you want

```
var gridData = (from d in db.billing_transactions
                where (d.Id > 954 && d.Id < 958)
                select new
                            {
                                d.base_amount,
                                d.Id,
                                dishmachine = d.billing_transaction_accessorial_charge
                                                .Where(p => p.service_code_id == 2)
                                                .Sum(x => x.amount),
                                residential = d.billing_transaction_accessorial_charge
                                                .Where(p => p.service_code_id == 1)
                                                .Sum(x => x.amount),
                            }).ToArray();
```

Comment: I did not realize you could link Lamdba expressions.  That works perfectly.  Thank you for helping me add it to my toolbox!  I'll accept it when it lets me.